# Where did Jon Snow get his sword?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

Whose sword did Jon Snow use to kill the White Walker in *Game of Thrones* S05E08?

Comment: It's **his** sword. Please **DO NOT** put **spoilers** in titles.

Comment: Now I think there is some value in previews before episode, they even showed it how Jon got it .

Comment: @StannisBaratheon Exactly. GoT has actually been pretty good at making valuable previews/flashbacks. That being said, I think the OP was confused that the sword he eventually used was actually **his** sword. It was clear to me but the fight scene was a bit frantic.

Comment: Come on, try to do some basic research first!

Answer (score 28):

In episode 9 of season 1 ("Baelor"), Jeor Mormont gave Jon Snow the Valyrian steel sword, Longclaw, in thanks for saving his life from a wight.

In the books, it originally had a bear's head as the pommel, but Mormont had the pommel refashioned into a wolf's head of pale stone with ruby eyes for Jon. It's a "bastard" or hand-and-a-half sword (half a foot longer than a longsword), rather than a longsword or greatsword.  It is the Mormont sword in the way that Ice was the Stark sword.  Jorah Mormont inherited it when his father took the black, but had enough honor to leave it behind when he was exiled in disgrace for trying to sell poachers into slavery, and Maege Mormont (Jeor's sister) who now rules Bear Island, sent it to Jeor at the Wall.

Comment: +1 I kind of assumed sword was made to look like ghost since he is Jon's direwolf.

Comment: Nice!  Thanks for this.  I think the OP may be confused to whether the sword Jon used on the White Walker was his own or not.  You might point that out but nice answer, in general.

Comment: @StannisBaratheon Yup. Didn't feel like mentioning the Ghost-appearance, though, since in the show, Ghost isn't an albino with red eyes. I also deleted an entire peroration on the Mormont women in the books (Maege being sent off to find Greywater and Howland Reed; Dacey buying it at the Red Wedding, etc.)

Comment: I have to admit that it was hard to tell that it was his sword, especially considering how he had a sword before that was shattered.